# how to read (Default) value in Registry Key in VBScript/JScript

Tags: wsh, jscript

I can read the value of the key name "UpdateCheck" under

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CCleaner\

with 
Shell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CCleaner\UpdateCheck")

But I cannot read that of the key name "(Default)" .

Shell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CCleaner\Default")

How to read it?

Answer (score 7):

Just pass the key name to RegRead and you'll get the default value. E.g.:

```
Shell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CCleaner\")
```

**NOTE**: Notice the trailing `\` in the regkey path. If that is missed out, it will try to read string value `CCleaner` from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`. Refer below .reg file snippet for more understanding.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE]
"CCleaner"="Some string value"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CCleaner]
@="some-default-value"
```